# Does focal length change when curbe mirror is dipped in liquid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

In a physical optics chapter, I found this question: Does the focal length change when a curve mirror is dipped into liquid?

Please explain it and help me understand.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Hint: the path of every ray entering each side of the lens is governed by Snell's law, $n_i\sin\theta_i = n_t\sin\theta_t$, where $i$ is the incident material and $t$ is the transmitted material (e.g., water to glass).

Answer (score 1):

In principe there is no effect of the medium. The imaging is determined by geometry only. The only effect that I can think of is that the phase jump due to reflection at the interface changes. This would change the effective location of the mirror surface by an amount of the order of (a fraction of) the wavelength. For an good metallic mirror this should not be relevant.